# Access Count if data occured in other column

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to count the number of employees working overtime for 2 consecutive days.

I have a table that looks like this

```
EmpID      Date       Hour
 A       2017/1/6      2
 A       2017/1/9      2
 A       2017/1/10     3
 B       2017/1/5      1
 B       2017/1/11     2
 C       2017/1/10     3
 C       2017/1/11     1
```

I am able to use the DateAdd function to find out the next day of the [Date] when an employee had worked overtime.

```
EmpID      Date       Hour      NextDay
 A       2017/1/6      2       2017/1/7
 A       2017/1/9      2       2017/1/10
 A       2017/1/10     3       2017/1/11
 B       2017/1/5      1       2017/1/6
 B       2017/1/11     2       2017/1/12
 C       2017/1/10     3       2017/1/11
 C       2017/1/11     1       2017/1/12
```

However, now, I am stuck after this.
In Excel, I am able to use countif() to check whether a [Date] that equals to [NextDay] appear in the table for each employee. Like the following table.

```
EmpID      Date       Hour      NextDay     OTNextDay
 A       2017/1/6      2       2017/1/7         0
 A       2017/1/9      2       2017/1/10        1
 A       2017/1/10     3       2017/1/11        0
 B       2017/1/5      1       2017/1/6         0
 B       2017/1/11     2       2017/1/12        0
 C       2017/1/10     3       2017/1/11        1
 C       2017/1/11     1       2017/1/12        0
```

Am I able to do similar things in Access?
This is my first question here. I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

The only easy approach I can see uses domain aggregate function. Working with your second dataset example:

`SELECT EmpID, [Date], Hour, NextDay, 
DCount("*","QueryName","EmpID='" & [EmpID] & "' And [Date]=#" & [NextDay] & "#") AS OTNextDate
FROM QueryName;`

Date and Hour are reserved words, should not use reserved words as names for anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple subquery:

```
SELECT 
    YourTable.EmpID, 
    YourTable.[Date], 
        DateAdd("d", 1, YourTable.[Date]) As 
    NextDay,
        (Select 
            Count(*) 
        From 
            YourTable As T 
        Where 
            T.EmpID = YourTable.EmpID 
            And 
            T.[Date] = DateAdd("d", 1, YourTable.[Date])) AS 
    OTNextDay
FROM 
    YourTable;
```